# Kubernetes Load Balancers AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, elastic-load-balancer

We've currently got a production application using Kubernetes on AWS. Everything's working very well except I think we've made a misconfiguration problem.

We expose different services from within the cluster on domain names and we're now up to about 5 different services. Kubernetes' standard way to expose these services is through load balancers, but in our config we've created 6 load balancers. As you can imagine that many load balancers running can incur substantial cost overheads.

Is there any way to configure an individual load balancer to route to kubernetes targets based on domain names? So we can have one domain pointing at an ELB and have that route to the correct services internally?

Comment: I'd recommend an ingress-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ingress controller. Ingress will setup a single AWS load balancer and can be used to expose many services. If you services are all HTTP based, it should work quite well. For more information about ingress you can have a look to the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) or at the default [Nginx based implementation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx). If needed there are also some other implementations using for example Envoy proxy etc.

Comment: I ended up using a traefik ingress controller and it worked quite well, thanks for this!